# Falcon 9 fuel use

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fuel

How much fuel does a Falcon 9 rocket used by SpaceX use, for a trip to the International Space Station?

Any possibility of Teslas batteries being used in the future?

Comment: What do batteries have to do with rocket fuel? This seems to either be two unrelated questions (in which case you should ask the second one separately) or a really confusing single question.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "rocket fuel $\rightarrow$ batteries" is a "beginner" question about technology, if cars can change from hydrocarbon to batteries, can rockets? You are right, that could be split off as a separate question, but it's not so horrible. Since there are one or two suitable answers below...

Answer (score 4):

Elon Musk has famously said that all transportation will eventually transition to electric EXCEPT rockets.

He included airplanes (and with the release of his Master Plan V2, trucks, buses, become more included) in that, claiming to have an idea for an electric airplane.

Mass of propellant on first stage, fuel + oxidizer is on the order of 395,700kg and it generates 1.5 million lbs of thrust so replacing that with batteries is unlikely to ever happen.

Answer (score 3):

The only electric rocket engines we use today are ion engines. Those still need a propellant (usually Xenon) and their thrust/weight ratio is far below 1 so we can't use those to launch a rocket from Earth.